# Function pointer code not executing properly

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

i am trying to learn function pointers and i just wanted to make 3 functions that have pointers to them which are used in other 2 functions which i am calling through function pointer arrays. The code doesn't give any errors, but i receive addresses instead of values. I tried dereferencing and such, but nothing changes. I am sure i am overlooking something simple, but i am not sure what to do, or where my mistake lies.

The explicit casting is there, because i was just playing around with it, no particular reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int par1(void)
{
    return 5;
}

unsigned int par2(void)
{
    return 6;
}

unsigned int par3(void)
{
    return 7;
}

const unsigned int x = 10;


typedef unsigned int (*parPtr)(void);
parPtr parP1 = &par1;
parPtr parP2 = &par2;
parPtr parP3 = &par3;

/** typedef for sum() and scad() */
typedef int (*sumscadPtr)(parPtr, parPtr);

sumscadPtr sumscadPtrArr[2];

int sum(parPtr, parPtr);

int scad(parPtr, const unsigned int);


void allocate_array_of_pointers(void)
{

    sumscadPtrArr[0] = &sum;
    sumscadPtrArr[1] = &scad;


}


// should return 11
int sum(parPtr parA, parPtr parB)
{
    unsigned int value1 = *parA;
    printf("\n%d\n", value1);
    unsigned int value2 = *parB;
    printf("\n%d\n", value2);

    return (int)value1 + (int)value2;
}


// should return 3
int scad(parPtr parA, unsigned const int b)
{
    unsigned int value1 = parA;

    // This is just a simple check in case i might change the const value in the future
    if((int)value1 > (int)b)
        return (int)value1 - (int)b;
    else
        return (int)b - (int)value1;
}




int main()
{
    allocate_array_of_pointers();

    int sumVal = sumscadPtrArr[0](&par1, &par2);
    int scadVal = sumscadPtrArr[1](&par3, x);

    printf("\nsumVal is :%d\n", sumVal);
    printf("\nscadVal is :%d\n", scadVal);

    int a = *parP1;
    printf("\n%d\n", a);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you not get any warnings from this code? `sum` and `scad` aren't the same signature so you can't put them in an array of `sumscadPtr`. If you have a function pointer you need to call it, not dereference it. `unsigned int value1 = *parA;` -> `unsigned int value1 = parA();`

Comment: As @RetiredNinja said, using `unsigned int value1 = *parA;` assigns the pointer (address) of the function pointed at by `parA` to `value1`, and if your compiler doesn't whinge vehemently about that assignment, you need a better compiler. Function pointers are weird. You don't need `&` in front of the function name to take its address; you can also use `*` rather liberally and end up with the same result.  Using `unsigned int value1 = parA();` would work properly, as would `unsigned value1 = (*parA)();` (which is the only notation that worked when I learned C — the alternative is from C90).

Comment: Hello again! Thank you very much for the replies, and for your insight, this helped me a lot! I received this little exercise from a friend, and based on what i learned from your comments it may be flawed. Nevertheless, on how to access the function pointers, both of you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code [failed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a635a1410346c08f) to compile with these errors:

```
main.cpp:42:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(parPtr, unsigned int)' {aka 'int (*)(unsigned int (*)(), unsigned int)'} to 'sumscadPtr' {aka 'int (*)(unsigned int (*)(), unsigned int (*)())'} [-fpermissive]
   42 |     sumscadPtrArr[1] = &scad;
```

which is quite obvious since your're storing the pointer to a function with a different function signature in `sumscadPtrArr[1]` other than `parPtr`.

and then:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'parPtr' {aka 'unsigned int (*)()'} to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
   51 |     unsigned int value1 = *parA;
```

and similar errors for all such invocations of applying the `*` to `parPtr` which is for assigning a `parPtr` to `unsigned int`. The correct way would be

```
unsigned int value1 = parA();
```

Function pointers cane be dereferenced in a couple of ways:

1. `(*fnPtr)()`
2. `fnPtr()`

The function pointer* array/table that you are attempting to create with `sumscadPtrArr` should ideally contain functions of the same type or you possibly could create a struct with something like:

```
struct fPtrTablle {
    int (*sumFn)(parPtr, parPtr);
    int (*scadFn)(parPtr, const unsigned int);
};

struct fPtrTablle FnTable = { sum, scad};

void initFnTable(void)
{
    FnTable.sumFn =  &sum;
    FnTable.scadFn = &scad;
}
```

and then call it from `main()` as:

```
initFnTable();

int sumVal = FnTable.sumFn(&par1, &par2);
int scadVal = FnTable.scadFn(&par3, x);
```

Complete compilable program [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a55e84a288197b2).

Comment: Thank you @Zoso, this was very enlightening, i did not think of the struct solution! My code compiled on code blocks, but i guess this is a compiler thing. Anyway, i know my code was flawed. Thanks again for pointing out my weaknesses!